# pip install pyzmail ERROR message

Tags: python, email, imapclient

I use Python 3.5.2.
I installed imapclient with no problem `pip install imapclient`. However when I tried to install pyzmail, `pip install pyzmail`, I received error message below:

```
    ImportError: No module named '_markerlib'
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\J
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ntukh55u\distribute\
```

Comment: have you tried "easy_install impaclient"?

Comment: I tried pip 'install --upgrade setuptools' and 'pip install ez_setup' and it didn't work and then I just tried 'pip install easy_install impaclient' and got error message _Collecting easy-install Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement easy-install (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for easy-install._  My error message is when I go to command line and type pip install pyzmail.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem, and resolved it using: easy_install pyzmail

Answer (score 35):

To those who find this thread and have switched to Python 3.6, this pyzmail fork enabling pip install on Python 3.6 worked very well for me :

```
 pip install pyzmail36
```

Comment: This helped me on mac. But i have actually used pip3 install pyzmail36

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue and solved it this way: type `pip install setuptools==20.1.1`, then try `pip install pyzmail` again. I had the latest version of setuptools (version 34.something) and it seems this version gets buggy when installing pyzmail.

Answer (score 0):

use pip install pyzmail36

This claims to be "a fork which is meant to be pip installable on python 3.6+".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using Python 3.8.5 on Windows 10.
After successfully installing imapclient, I used this command, which worked fine:

```
pip install --user pyzmail36==1.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have already solve the problems , I hope 'yes' , but it is very easy you need just to writte

```
pip install --user pyzmail36*
```

It will install properly the last version ! but take a look at your python version ---> python --version  because sometimes it needs to be update .