# Pyzmail successfully installed, but there is still an error message

Tags: python, pyzmail

I have Python 3.7 installed on my laptop and want to install the module called **pyzmail**. It does work, but I still get the error message **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyzmail'** in Spyder.

I know that there are at least two finished questions concerning this: 
[pip failed with error code 1 while installing pyzmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144887/pip-failed-with-error-code-1-while-installing-pyzmail)
[pip install pyzmail ERROR message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924672/pip-install-pyzmail-error-message), 
but neither cover my problem

At first, I tried to install **pyzmail** via the cmd, but *pip install pyzmail* did not work. In addition to that, neither *pip easy_install pyzmail* nor *easy_install pyzmail* seemed to do the work. BUT the solution was (at lest for me) to insert the following line into cmd: *pip install pyzmail36*.

So the package is installed, but I still get an error message. I restarted my laptop at least twice after pyzmail36 was (successfully) installed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

does nobody have an idea? Since I am new contributor, I have just been wondering that I have not received an answer yet.